# What is Python 's default setting for width on String Operations and how is it different that "0"?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, width, operation

I'm beginning to get into programming and cannot decipher yet the answer that I got from Python.org on this, and it looks like no one asked this question before.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between

```
"You have $%.2f left in your piggy bank" % totalCash
```

and

```
"You have $%0.2f left in your piggy bank" % totalCash
```

According to the book I am studying (Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science, by John Zelle): "You can use a 0 width to indicate "use as much space as needed." What doesn't make sense is, *It is already using as much space as needed*. If I put in that I have 100000.42 in my variable it still prints it with the correct amount of space regardless of whether or not I put the "0" as the width or not.

The output is identical.

So it seems to me that "0" the default width set, but then I looked at the documentation on Python.org and they say the same thing, but with some highly-technical words I don't understand

" Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '=' "

I don't understand that at all, but I do understand this next line which sounds like it is the same as what I thought the "0" did:

" width is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content. "

So what is the difference, can anyone explain?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that neither is the correct way to do things now. Now we use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), but a similar format exists.

Basically, use of the `0` means if your DATA is shorter than your WIDTH, it will zero-fill to fill the width.

```
>>> "{:8}".format(12)
'      12'
>>> "{:08}".format(12)
'00000012'   # different when data is shorter than width
>>> "{:8}".format(1234567890)
'1234567890'
>>> "{:08}".format(1234567890)
'1234567890' # no difference when data is longer than width
```

In old-style [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), this would be:

```
>>> "%8d" % 12
'      12'
>>> "%08d" % 12
'00000012'
>>> "%8d" % 1234567890
'1234567890' # still no change
>>> "%08d" % 1234567890
'1234567890' # when data is longer than width
```

Comment: Maybe use different numbers to indicate the difference?

Comment: Hey Adam, Thanks a lot! I see how adding the 0 in front of a specified width makes it "zero-fill" the output. 

So then the "0" alone does nothing really? (Just as I thought?) 

Kind of blows that I'm studying old string interpolation. Was that replaced in Python 3+? Do you have any suggestions on good books to read for the most recent stuff? I'm getting into programming for a long-term profession and am getting my hands on everything I can to learn.

Comment: @affinities23 No problem! If my answer helped, please consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). I couldn't tell you when `str.format` started gaining use over the `%` iterpolation marker, but I'm sure you could go through the docs and find it. As far as literature on the subject, I'm actually not a great source for that because everything I've ever learned about coding I've done by trudging through docs pages and googling for tutorials. Unfortunately Stack Overflow can't really help you there either ("finding an off-site resource" is a close reason!)

Comment: @affinities23 the `0` doesn't do anything on its own because without the width field next to it, you're setting the MINWIDTH for the field to be zero. Of course any string will meet or exceed that minimum width, so you never see any change. The `0` flag you're looking for can only exist with a defined field width, and simply fills space. Using `str.format` you can actually fill with any character (try `print("{:=^70}".format("Header"))`) not just zero.

Comment: @AdamSmith Cool, I accepted your answer. This is my first question I asked on Stack Overflow, so I didn't even know how to accept an answer! I tried your code print("{:=^70}".format("Header")) and it's pretty cool. Thanks for the warm welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `0` format character has to be followed by the `width` you want to achieve:

```
>>> "You have $%08.2f left in your piggy bank" % 1.2
'You have $00001.20 left in your piggy bank'
>>> "You have $%08.2f left in your piggy bank" % 10.2
'You have $00010.20 left in your piggy bank'
```